# Using NPX to Create a Project

Tags: node.js, npm, npx

With the following commands I can create the following projects:

- `npx create-react-app`:  a react project.
- `npx create-next-app`: a next.js project.
- `npx create-strapi-app`: a strapi project.

I am wondering, how can I create my own project that with my own `npx create-[project-name]-app` command? That is to say, a project where a number of files and folders & npm packages are installed and ready to use.

Is there any documentation and/or guides on how to do this.  I have done a number of searches and can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Check out, [this blog post](https://medium.com/@maybekatz/introducing-npx-an-npm-package-runner-55f7d4bd282b). it goes over how to create the npx scripts.